# i want to parse data image from curl bases web service in objective c and I am using that code

Tags: ios

- I want to get data from curl web service ,but my code is not working

  ```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:delegate.profilePic];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:picUrl];   
       [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [req setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSString *token =delegate.Token;
        [req setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
       [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
       NSError *error = nil;
       NSURLResponse *response;
     NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
     NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Url Data %@",myString);
  ```

Comment: That's really nice code ! What's the problem ?

Comment: For starters, you're missing the end of this line of code: `NSURL *picUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"`. Please fix it so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with this code, i used this to get image data

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:delegate.profilePic];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSString *boundary = @"0x0hHai1CanHazB0undar135";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [req addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [req setValue:delegate.Token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         profilePicView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:urlData];
    });
});
```